# How to find the average time from log file for a specific pattern matched string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have logs with the following pattern, I need a shell script which can grep the pattern `Forged new block id` and calculate the average time from the timestamp column for the matching pattern `Forged new block id`.

```
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:32:20 | Forged new block id: 17422268043238265953 height: 6 round: 1 slot: 6372914 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:32:30 | Forged new block id: 12637471709620273874 height: 7 round: 1 slot: 6372915 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:33:31 | Forged new block id: 9854455515089974346 height: 13 round: 1 slot: 6372921 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:35:34 | Forged new block id: 9528299565814967922 height: 25 round: 1 slot: 6372933 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:37:44 | Forged new block id: 4030154355419311374 height: 38 round: 1 slot: 6372946 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:38:34 | Forged new block id: 15961811681976216620 height: 43 round: 1 slot: 6372951 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:39:03 | Forged new block id: 18327854550540255433 height: 46 round: 1 slot: 6372954 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:43:05 | Forged new block id: 6436183970195006511 height: 70 round: 1 slot: 6372978 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:44:34 | Forged new block id: 2865139280099855691 height: 79 round: 1 slot: 6372987 reward: 0
[inf] 2018-06-01 07:45:45 | Forged new block id: 5462796790425133759 height: 86 round: 1 slot: 6372994 reward: 0
```

The expected result is the time difference between current row and its previous row lets say `2018-06-01 07:32:20` this is the first row and this is the second row `2018-06-01 07:32:30` so the time difference is `10 seconds` and the average would be the sum of all the difference and divided by total rows

Comment: what should be the expected result, a timestamp or datetime string?

Comment: is shell script mandatory? shell is not best for file parsing; use some scripting language like Python, perl, etc; I would go with Python as personal pref, especially because its by default on every nix system so no pain.

Comment: Python, Javascript script should also be fine

Comment: what the 3rd record should be compared with? with the 2nd record's initial datetime OR with the difference of the 2nd and 1st records?

Comment: Don't just describe the expected output, **show** us **the** expected output given the sample input you provided.

Comment: Please select one of the answers , they all seem legit

Answer (score 3):

You could use this GNU `awk` script:

```
$ awk '/Forged new block id/{timestr=$2" "$3;gsub(/[-:]/," ",timestr);t1=mktime(timestr);if(t2) {diff=t1-t2;print diff} t2=t1; total+=diff} END{print "average=" total/NR}' file
10
61
123
130
50
29
242
89
71
average=80.5
```

The script converts the 2nd and 3th field into a date string that `mktime` awk command understand.

The timestamp difference is calculated based on the last line.

The `END` prints the average in seconds.

Comment: That's GNU awk only.

Comment: @Manu You indeed need GNU awk (that might not be the default on your mac). `brew install gawk` might help.

Comment: I tried installing `gawk`, now i am getting error `calling undefined function mktime`
Note: I am using mac

Comment: @Manu it is likely that you still use the default  `awk`. Use `gawk` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` to calculate average time:

```
awk 'function getSec(s) {
   cmd = "date +%s -d \"" s "\""
   cmd | getline d
   close( cmd )
   return d
}
/Forged new block id/ {
   ++n
   ts = $2 OFS $3
   if (n == 1)
      start = ts
}
END {
   print (getSec(ts) - getSec(start)) / n
}' file
```

```
80.5
```

[Online Working Demo](https://ideone.com/74ktVH)

Comment: I think it throws an error
$ awk 'function getSec(s) {
   cmd = "date +%s -d \"" s "\""
   cmd | getline d
   close( cmd )
   return d
}
/Forged new block id/ {
   ++n
   ts = $2 OFS $3
   if (n == 1)
      start = ts
}
END {
   print (getSec(ts) - getSec(start)) / n
}' test/test.txt
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]

Comment: [Here is an online working demo of above code](https://ideone.com/74ktVH)

Comment: The code relies on a `date` command that supports `%s` output format and allows you to provide a date to be converted but that's all non-POSIX so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the times into timestamps and do the math on them.

eg. turn human to epoch (eg. "Apr 28 07:50:01" to 1524916201) and then subtract them add them or whatever.

In this example I have a function that will go from "human" readable if you will to timestamp and back. I found this useful when I wrote a script to tell me when crons started and when they actually completed.

Example: Convert from human to epoch function

```
#!/bin/bash
# -- Converts from human to epoch or epoch to human, 
#    specifically this format: "Apr 28 07:50:01" human.
#    typeset now=$(date +"%s")
#    typeset now_human_date=$(convert_cron_time "human" "$now")

function convert_cron_time() {
    case "${1,,}" in
        epoch)
            # human to epoch (eg. "Apr 28 07:50:01" to 1524916201)
            echo $(date -d "${2}" +"%s")
            ;;
        human)
            # epoch to human (eg. 1524916201 to "Apr 28 07:50:01")
            echo $(date -d "@${2}" +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
            ;;
    esac
}


now=$(date +"%s")
time_range=604800   #one week in seconds
start=$now
finish=$((($now+$time_range)))


start_human=$(convert_cron_time "human" "$start")
finish_human=$(convert_cron_time "human" "$finish")

start_epoch=$(convert_cron_time "epoch" "$start_human")
finish_epoch=$(convert_cron_time "epoch" "$finish_human")

echo "$start_human / $start_epoch"
echo "$finish_human / $finish_epoch"

another=$(convert_cron_time "epoch" "2018-06-01 07:32:20")
another_human=$(convert_cron_time "human" "$another")
echo "another ex: $another / $another_human"
```

Output:

```
Jun 01 08:47:34 / 1527857254
Jun 08 08:47:34 / 1528462054
another ex: 1527852740 / Jun 01 07:32:20
```

Hence, in a for loop you can add all of the fields up or do comparisons as you are reading the file. In your case you would subtract the timestamps and take the difference in seconds and do something with them (e.g. convert to mins/hours etc.)